# How to create a custom button for Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I want to make a custom button in shape of a picture with `C#` for a `Windows Store App`?

Is there a way to do that from `xaml`? So far I've made a button and assigned a circle as a background image, but the problem is that even if I click outside the image the button works.

Also I do not believe that `Image` class has an `event` for `click` unfortunately.

Comment: Brief example without much explanation, but it is a complete example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709909.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently implemented the WinRT XAML toolkit and it works wonder for me.  It has an imagebutton control that might do what you want to do.  http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

With the help of google: [Walkthrough: Create a Button by Using XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613545.aspx)

You should have a look into Expression Blend. You can do all manualy in the XAML-Code but Blend is a huge help if you like to customize your project look and feel. Look at the [MSDN-Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc136522.aspx).

Comment: That link is for WPF, not Windows Store apps.